# Java FX and Database Connection

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

I want to write a JavaFX program with Database Connection(MYSQL). I did not know how to create a connection in program. And the methods I found on internet is not working for me. (Possibly because of the version difference or something.) Can anyone give the procedure to establish a connection and run a query from the program for the latest version of JavaFX?!

Thanks.

Naren

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest taking a look at [DataFX](http://www.javafxdata.org/)

Answer (score 0):

User interfaces should not be connecting directly to a database.

Put a servlet in-between to act as an intermediary.  Let it do security, validation, binding, and such, too.

You're finding it hard because you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can see my post in [javamexico.org](http://javamexico.org), where I talk about connecting mysql with java and javafx. it´s written in spanish but just look at the code.
http://javamexico.org/foros/java_enterprise/tratamiento_de_imagenes#comment-3738